# jQuery: size/length of dynamically loaded elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a form and I'm dynamically adding new input & select elements in to it via jQuery's load function. Sometimes the loaded elements are in purpose empty and in that case I want to hide the container div so it won't break the style.

The problem is, that I seem to be unable to count the loaded elements and therefore don't know if it should be hidden or not.

For example I have this:

```
<div id="param_container"></div>
```

And on some dropdown menu change I have binded this function:

```
alert($('#param_container').children().length);

// Returns and loads new element correctly. Can be empty.
$('#param_container').load('/get_params', {cat:category});

if ($('#param_container').children().length ) {
    $('#param_container').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('#param_container').css('display', 'none');
}

alert($('#param_container').children().length);
```

The length of the children are always 0 even though new children element has been added.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

My solution

```
$('#param_container').load('/get_params', {cat:category}, function(response) {
    if (response) {
        $('#param_container').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('#param_container').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Solved this on my own :) used .load's callback function to check the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) call is *asynchronous*, it completes after your function returns.

You can use the success callback, like this:

```
alert($('#param_container').children().length);

// Returns and loads new element correctly. Can be empty.
$('#param_container').load('/get_params', {cat:category}, function() {
    if ($('#param_container').children().length ) {
        $('#param_container').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('#param_container').css('display', 'none');
    }

    alert($('#param_container').children().length);
});
```

Comment: I ended in almost same solution, this is even better though. Thanks!

Comment: @Seerumi: I should have said in the above that it may be worthwhile looking up the element *once* and remembering it in a variable, rather than re-running `$("#param_container")` every time. Every time you call `$`, it results in several function calls and memory allocations. The browser will clean them up eventually, of course, but...

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove the # from the id of the div i.e

you wrote:

```
<div id="#param_container"></div>
```

you need:

```
<div id="param_container"></div>
```

When you write $('#param_container') in jQuery it means that you what an element where the id equals the string without the '#' sign. so you don't need to include it in the html code.

Comment: This is half the problem, I don't see any need for people to downvote it.

Comment: Apparently, though, it was just a typo in the question which the OP has fixed, so this should probably be deleted now.

Comment: + 1000 internets for you and +500 internets for everyone else.  I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you can try complete callback as mention with load API [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

```
$('#param_container').load('/get_params', {cat:category}, 
function() {
if ($('#param_container').children().length ) {
    $('#param_container').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('#param_container').css('display', 'none');
}
}
);
```